# Laravel - Paginating Eloquent Retrieved results

Tags: pagination, laravel, eloquent

This what i have in my controller

```
$projects=Project::where_sup_id($user_id)->get();
   $total=count($projects);
   $per_page=3;
  $projects = Paginator::make($projects, $total, $per_page);
  return View::make('project.index')->with('projects',$projects);
```

And this in my View

```
 @foreach ($projects->results as $project) 

      {{$project->title}}

 @endforeach


{{$projects->links();}}
```

but when i view it in the browser it is displaying all rows in all pages...the links are displaying perfectly! what do u think is the problem? please help! thank u in advance!

Comment: Fixed on error and then ended up with another -- don't forget about the need for `->results` or you'll get an ambiguous `Trying to get property of non-object` error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are counting all rows, but not using `limit` at all, Laravel fluent query builder has `skip()` and `take()` method for that.

Btw, you don't need to manually paginate it. Laravel does pagination automatically with  `paginate()` method.

Do it that way:

```
$projects = Project::where_sup_id($user_id)->paginate(3); // 3 means records per page
return View::make('project.index')->with('projects', $projects);
```

You are doing `view` work correctly.